# Regexp to fit all string NOT ending with a LIST of known suffixes (not characters, but words)

Tags: java, regex

I need to be able to build a regexp capturing all possible patterns, except for the strings ending with `b` or `i` or `f` or `dt`.

My string always starts with words and has an underscore before the closing suffix.
If I didn't have the `dt` in the blacklist of suffixes, I would probably do something like the following: 

`\w+_[^f|b|i]+ OR maybe (.*)_[^f|b|i]`

But the `[^x|y|z]` format only captures single characters, and I wasn't able to combine it with a sequence of characters.

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Aside from main question, `|` in `[^x|y|z]` is simple *character*, not OR operator. You probably meant `[^xyz]`

Comment: Try [`s.matches(".*(?<![bif]|dt)")`](https://ideone.com/482ADY). Or negate [`"(?:[bif]|dt)\\z"`](https://ideone.com/yw4Iyr)

Comment: Maybe [`^(?!.+_(?:[bif]|dt)$)\w+.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/0kfNaI/1) using a negative lookahead.

Comment: Ah, yeah, if `_` must be there, 1) [`s.matches(".*(?<!_[bif]|_dt)")`](https://ideone.com/DJrZCc) or 2) [`"_(?:[bif]|dt)\\z"`](https://ideone.com/XZ5f5t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want to match always starts with word characters and  contains an underscore before the closing suffix you might match one or more word characters `\w+`, match an underscore and then match one or more word charcters `\w+`

Then use a negative lookbehind to assert that what is on the left side is not `b`, `f`, `i` or `dt` and end with a word boundary `\b` to make sure the suffix is not part of a larger word.

[`\w+_\w+(?<![bfi]|dt)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/8EjMMv/1)

**Details**

- `\w+_\w+` Match one or more word characters, an `_` and again one or more word characters
- `(?<!` Negative lookbehind

  - `[bfi]` [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which match b, f or i
  - `|` Or
  - `dt` Match literally
- `)` Close negative lookbehind
- `\b` Word boundary

[Demo Java](http://rextester.com/DKND7850)

Answer (score 1):

Note that `.*_[^f|b|i]` with `matches()` does not mean *match if does not end with*, it means *match if it ends with a char other than the one(s) defined in the character set*. However, in this case, it seems to make no difference. The only trouble is that `|` is treated as a pipe char in the character class, and `dt` will be treated as 2 separate chars if you place it inside the character class.

You have at least 2 options (there can be more): use a regex that matches any string that does not end with a `_` followed with `b`, `i`, `f` or `dt` or match these letters/combinations of letters with the underscore at the end of the string and negate the result.

[Approach 1](https://ideone.com/DJrZCc):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("aaaa_b", "zzzzzz_i", "---------_f", "TTTTT_dt", "..._.");
        for (String str : strs)
            System.out.println("\"" + str + "\": " + str.matches(".*(?<!_[bif]|_dt)"));
```

Output:

```
"aaaa_b": false
"zzzzzz_i": false
"---------_f": false
"TTTTT_dt": false
"..._.": true
```

**NOTE**: To make it case insensitve, you may prepend the pattern with `(?i)`, `"(?i).*(?<!_[bif]|_dt)"`. Also, the `.` does not match line breaks by default, you may want to let it match them with `(?s)`, `"(?si).*(?<!_[bif]|_dt)"`.

[Approach 2](https://ideone.com/XZ5f5t):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("aaaa_b", "zzzzzz_i", "---------_f", "TTTTT_dt", "..._.");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("_(?:[bif]|dt)\\z");
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println("\"" + str + "\": " + !p.matcher(str).find());
}
```

Output is the same. Same case insensitivity note applies.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! This is great, I was unable to make it work with my specific use case (I needed it for ElasticSeach dynamic mapping regexp match pattern), but thanks so much for your time and effort :)